# python new line from array

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I am using Jinja template in the frontend and in my backend I am using python using which I have an array which is of type string:

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    match = ''
    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        #file stuff



discription = ""
for file in files:
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    #OCR related stuffs
      
      
        for i in range(0, output_ocr_len):
            #preprocessing
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                            

        if cord_len > 0:
            height = result_img.shape[0]
            width = result_img.shape[1]

            for elements in range(0, cord_len):

            char_length = []
            predicted_pattern_category = numpy.append(
                predicted_pattern_category, 'Misdirection')
            [char_length.append(x)
             for x in predicted_pattern_category if x not in char_length]
            your_predicted_pattern_category = str(char_length)
            char_length = []
            predicted_pattern_type = numpy.append(
                predicted_pattern_type, 'Visual Interference')
            [char_length.append(x) for x in predicted_pattern_type if x not in char_length]
            your_predicted_pattern_type = ""  + str(char_length)
            for i in range(0,len(char_length)):
                print("from ML :-",char_length[i])
                index_of_key = key.index(char_length[i])
                discription = discription +  ""  + value[index_of_key]
            print(discription)
            match = str(match) + " "
        else:
            
            char_length = []

            
            [char_length.append(x)
             for x in predicted_pattern_category if x not in char_length]
            your_predicted_pattern_category = str(char_length)

            if len(your_predicted_pattern_category) < 3: 
                your_predicted_pattern_category=''
            char_length = []
            [char_length.append(x) for x in predicted_pattern_type if x not in char_length]
            your_predicted_pattern_type =  str(char_length)
            
            if len(your_predicted_pattern_type) < 3: 
                your_predicted_pattern_type=''
                
            for i in range(0,len(char_length)):
                print("from ML :-",char_length[i])
                index_of_key = key.index(char_length[i])
                discription = discription +  '\r\n'  + value[index_of_key]
            print(discription)

        return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                               msg='Processed successfully!',
                               match=match,
                               discription=discription
                               filenames=output_results
                               )
    else:

        return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                               msg='Processed successfully!',
                               match=match,
                               filenames=file_names)
```

To display the description, I am using Jinja template:

```
<tr>
    <th class="table-info">Description</th>

        <td>{{ description }}</td>

   
</tr>
```

**I want that the description is printed on a new line whose content is present within the "value" variable.**

**currently the description renders together and not in a new line:**

> happy: is an emotionis: an extensionmy mood: relies on people

**What I want is (every sentence in a new line)**

```
 happy: is an emotionis: 
 an extensionmy mood: 
 relies on people
```

Comment: It's spelled "description", btw.

Comment: I have made changes, however would you know the answer to this? @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your code comes out on one line because you're repeatedly appending to the same variable. If you really want it all in one variable `description`, and on separate lines, I think you need a new line char, but I think HTML *may* ignore them...

For your fundamental problem, tables are designed to have information on separate rows. If you want the descriptions to be on separate lines, I think separate rows is the way to go. I would personally do the for-loop in the template instead of the backend.

```html
{% for value in values %}
<tr>
    <th class="table-info">Description</th>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesn't work :(

Comment: @EverydayDeveloper You need to rewrite your question, as it currently isn't particularly clear. You've got variables in the code examples that aren't defined to us, and the indentation is all over the place.

Comment: Actually the code is 500 lines long with nested loops (therefore this indentation), however the description variable relies on only key and value. The solution provided by you prints every letter in new row instead of the string from the array @askman.

Comment: If it's 500 lines long, you need to cut it down to its most simplified form as a minimal reproducible example, see if you can get the logic you want, and then build it back up to where you need it to be

Comment: Done! Can you please have a look :) @askman

Comment: Does changing this line `discription = discription +  ""  + value[index_of_key]` to `discription = discription +  ""  + value[index_of_key] + "\n"` do what you want it to?

Comment: This is working similar to the for loop. It is only adding blank space between each letter instead of breaking sentences into next line @askman